# Use a string to call commands in Octave

Tags: command, octave

Suppose I define

```
Octave:1>s = "hello";
Octave:2>mkdir s
Octave:3>cd s
```

This creates a directory named `s` (instead of `hello`), and changes to that directory. How to use `hello` instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
mkdir(s)
cd(s)
```

Take a look at functional vs command syntax: https://octave.org/doc/v5.2.0/Commands.html

Comment: Just asking, did you already know this from experience, or did you find it in the docs? The docs contain everything, but I often cannot find the relevant doc because I don't know which section to look at.

Comment: Hi @ArchismanPanigrahi, you can easily search within the docs from duckduckgo or google by prepending "site:" and the url  you want to search from in the query. E.g. search for  `commands site:octave.org/doc/v5.2.0/` in duckduckgo to see what results come out!